# jquery - How do I execute function after ajax call

Tags: jquery

This problem is now solved and I no longer need help.

I have this code and am experiencing some problems

```
$.ajax({
  url: this.html_url,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
        $('body:last-child').append(html);
        return true;
  }
});
doSomething();
```

My problem is that doSomething is called before the ajax success function has completed. I would like doSomething to be called immediately after the ajax call is completed including the success function. Any help?

Comment: why don't you add doSomething() to ajax success?

Comment: If the problem is solved, share the solution or delete your question

Comment: @maximus you are right just need to add doSomething() to ajax success please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in the callback!

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.html_url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
        $('body:last-child').append(html);
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: this.html_url,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
            $('body:last-child').append(html);
            doSomething();
            return true;
      }
   });
```

Or use promises.

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` is a async function so you should put your `doSomething` function in the `success` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your function inside success like as below.

```
$.ajax({
  url: this.html_url,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
        $('body:last-child').append(html);
        doSomething();
        return true;
  }
});
```